# Loop through a custom resource file in kentico 8

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, repeater, kentico

I've built a `.aspx`template which contains a dropdown *(no .asp control)*.

Template sample:

```
<select>
    <option selected="selected" value="">Bitte w&auml;hlen</option>
    <asp:Repeater ID="countryDropDown" runat="server">

        <HeaderTemplate>
            <option value="<%--key--%>">
        </HeaderTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>
            <%--value--%>
        </ItemTemplate>

        <FooterTemplate>
            </option>
        </FooterTemplate>

    </asp:Repeater>
</select>
```

This dropdown should contain all countries. All countries are stored in `Custom.resex` which is placed in the `CMSResoures` folder which is Kentico specific.

Now i want to iterate through the file and pass a list of countries to the repeater. 
I'm not able to find a solution for this.

Of course it's easy to get a specific value through the key with the Kentico `ResHelper.GetString("stringKey")` function but not found a way to receive all entries using the Kentico library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this the super easy way, then just register the Country Selecter that's found in ~/CMSFormControls/CountrySelector.ascx like this:

It has the same function as what you appear to be working on.

However, for future reference, all of the countries are already stored in the CMS_Countries table in the DB.  It would be much easier to populate a DataSet with all of the countries, then assign the DataSet as the repeater's datasource.  Here is one of numerous ways to do this:

```
//Set the connection string to the Kentico Database in the web.config to a variable called CMSConnectionString
string CMSConnectionString = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CMSConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

//Sets the text of the query we want to execute on the database to a variable called queryText
string queryText = "SELECT * FROM dbo.CMS_Countries";

//Creates a new instance of the SqlDataAdapter object and calls it "adapter".  
//We pass in the text of the query we want to executre on the Kentico database, and the connetion string to the Kentico database.
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryText, CMSConnectionString);

//Creates a new instance of the DataSet object and calls it "countries".
DataSet countries = new DataSet();

//Fills the "countries" dataset with the data retrieved by our query on the Kentico database.
adapter.Fill(countries);

//Sets the datasource of the repeater to the dataset that we just created.
repeater.DataSource = countries;

//Binds the datasource to the repeater server control
repeater.DataBind();
```

Finally, if you absolutely have to use the CMS.resx file, then you should check out .[how to populate a datatable with XML](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how%20to%20populate%20a%20dataset%20with%20xml).